# I don't understand why a flag was disputed

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

In [my flagged post list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2633423) I've just seen that a "not an answer" flag I raised for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914370/where-does-a-published-rdl-file-sit/19325413#19325413) has been disputed.

I don't understand why and what I did wrong. The post is clearly almost a copy of [a part of a previous answer on the same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068307/2633423). The only added information is very minor: the database name and schema `ReportServer.dbo.`. I don't remember when I flagged that answer, but probably was in the low quality queue (not sure). Anyway it should not be an answer as per SO guidelines, it is really a so small a contribution it should be in a comment.

What did I miss?

Comment: That's an answer. Maybe not a good one, but still honest attempt to answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I agree it could have been made in good faith, but really almost cut and paste from the previous answer.

Comment: It's important to note the approved flags are used to load audits, as such if it is an answer (even if it should be deleted for other reasons) the flag must be declined

Comment: @Sancho My point wasn't about the correctness of the answerer's behavior, but about the quality of the answer. It doesn't SO a good service if any user copies an already posted answer (maybe a good one), changes 1% of it and repost it. It is almost the same as posting one-liners as answers.

Comment: @RichardTingle Good to know! thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should explain that in your flag. To me, and probably to the person who flagged your flag as invalid as well as the moderator who handled the flags, it's not immediately obvious why it isn't an answer. You used a very broad, vague "not an answer" flag which could have probably used some details as to why you thought it was not an answer.

Looking at it more closely here, I do believe this was an attempt to comment on the answer above it, so I've gone ahead and deleted it.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it. So what should I've done? Should I have used the custom flag with a more detailed explanation?  thought the custom flags were for exceptional things since they go directly to the mods, if I'm not mistaken. Is such a "borderline not an answer" case worth a custom flag then?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Custom flags should be used when one of the canonical flags doesn't accurately describe the problem or what should be done with the post. Here, a "not an answer" flag just isn't enough detail, so yes, a custom flag to describe in more detail would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind. BTW, does that disputed flag affects my review record negatively? Or is it something I shouldn't care too much?

Comment: A disputed flag does not affect you in any way, positive or negative.